# Providing access to the SQL server database for outside developers

Tags: sql-server

I am beginning a project that will involve insert and updates to a sql server database from a website. I maintain the SQL server database and am providing access to the sql server db.

My plan is to create a user with read/write access and provide the outsourced developers with a connection string with access to views that I create. Please let me know if this is outside the development expectations or if anyone has recommendations.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what exactly your question is. However, let me try an answer...

In general it is a good idea to have all application access go exclusively through a layer of views and procedures. That allows to run multi step migrations under the covers without impacting the running application. Through that you can implement changes like moving a column of a 2 TB table to another table without downtime.

It is also a good practice to restrict application access to only the minimum required level. So giving the app read/write access to just the views and procedures is a good idea.

Finally, any web developer should know how to use a connection string. So if that is your question, you are good there too.

If you were going for something else, leave a comment below.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is create a user (or users, depending on the granularity of auditing and permission sets) and then preferably create a database role.  That way you are granting and denying permissions on the role and having the members subject to them. This will give you the full control over what those database users can and cannot do. It's all about the principle of least privileged. Only allow what you want them to do, and nothing more. Whether it's on the database, schema, individual objects etc.

Answer (score 1):

The most secure option will be to setup VPN to the office/data center that the SQL Server is at, then have the developers VPN into the site.  Then give them either a SQL login or create Windows logins for them to use so that they can connect.